# Referencing the current server in Capistrano task

Tags: php, ruby, deployment, capistrano, apc

How would I reference the current server in a Capistrano task? I want to `curl` a local file to clear the APC cache but the server does not listen on `localhost` so I need the server's IP address.

For instance,

```
role :web, "1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2", "3.3.3.3"

task :clear_apc, :role => :web do
    run "curl http://#{WHAT_DO_I_PUT_HERE}/deploy/clearAPC.php"
end
```

What variable would I use so that when the task is run on 1.1.1.1 it `curl`s `http://1.1.1.1/deploy/clearAPC.php` but when run on 2.2.2.2 it calls `curl`s `http://2.2.2.2/deploy/clearAPC.php`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's the magical $CAPISTRANO:HOST$

```
run "curl http://$CAPISTRANO:HOST$/deploy/clearAPC.php"
```

should do exactly what you want.

note: don't use it as a variable via string interpolation, capistrano will just replace the $CAPISTRANO:HOST$ in the string itself.

That's a very weird and (afaik) undocumented feature :-)

Comment: This looks really hacky. Why didn't the Capistrano guys make it a method?

Comment: maybe @leehambley knows the answer ;) I'll point him to this question

Comment: user1158559 has a much better answer, though it's not the accepted one.

Comment: @Nate the question was how to access the hostname and that's the fastest way. Could you please elaborate why you prefere the way longer method below over the my solution, considering the original question?

Comment: Because good lord, is $CAPISTRANO:HOST$ ugly as sin. It looks like magic. Making the loop explicit seems like a good idea to me. It is worth noting: it is documented here: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Action-Invocation-Run

Comment: @Nate I never said it's beautiful, but I answered the original question. I do however respect your opinion, I just didn't see the reason for the downvote because the answer is 100% legit

Comment: Sigh, you're right; it really didn't deserve a downvote. However, SO doesn't seem to let me undownvote it :/

Comment: Technically the OP asked what should be put inside his ruby string interpolation and what variable he should use! :)

Answer (score 29):

In Capistrano, tasks don't get executed once for each server, run executes your command on each server. Here is what you should do instead:

```
task :clear_apc, :role => :web do
    find_servers_for_task(current_task).each do |current_server|

        run "curl http://#{current_server.host}/deploy/clearAPC.php", :hosts => current_server.host

    end
end
```

The accepted answer will work, but this one lets you access the servers as variables/methods

Comment: `find_servers_for_task` works exactly as described. Thank you!

Comment: This works better than the accepted answer, especially if you decide to use capture() instead of run().

Answer (score 3):

```
current_host = capture("echo $CAPISTRANO:HOST$").strip
```

Comment: I prefer this. For `system` commands, $CAPISTRANO:HOST$ doesn't work while using this works great.

Answer (score 1):

Capistrano 3 - server is available as an object, with set of properties, in the roles block :

`on roles(:app)  do |server|`

So for example to pass the hostname property to docker compose

```
  on roles(:app)  do |server|
    execute "docker-compose --build-arg SOME_HOST_NEEDED=#{server.hostname} ......
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know the current server I was deploying to, so that I could send a message to campfire. This is what I was able to figure out, though I'm sure there is a better way

```
 actions = current_task.namespace.parent.logger.instance_variable_get('@options')[:actions]
 message = "I am deploying #{fetch(:latest_release).split('/').last} using cap #{actions.join(' ')}"
```

so when I deploy it posts this to campfire
I am deploying 20121206154442 using cap QA2 campfire:notify deploy deploy:flex_master

Answer (score 0):

capistrano (2.13.5) required

```
puts current_task.namespace.logger.instance_variable_get('@base_logger').instance_variable_get('@options')[:actions].join(' ')
```

figured this out by

```
puts current_task.namespace.logger.inspect
```